# PyTorch error when downloading https://github.com/zeyad-mansour/lunar

Tags: pytorch

pip install pytorch
Collecting pytorch
Using cached pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz (689 bytes)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\isamu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ib00i94p\pytorch_f353fda7bc1a41bdabf99f644cf66bcb\setup.py", line 15, in 
raise Exception(message)
Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch
Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pytorch did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\isamu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ib00i94p\pytorch_f353fda7bc1a41bdabf99f644cf66bcb\setup.py", line 11, in 
raise Exception(message)
Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pytorch

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

tried:

```
pip install torch
```

```
pip3 install efficiencynet_pytorch
```

```
pip install pytorch
```

- but didn't help

Comment: tried "pip3 install efficiencynet_pytorch" but didn't help

Comment: What is the output of `pip install torch` ?

Comment: I doubt the error is the same for all the combinations you've tried. If yes, check your `requirements.txt` and remove `pytorch`.